# vbscript objExplorer.Document.Body.innerhtml does not work as local user from 3rd partry app

Tags: vbscript

Ok gurus,
I am in no way a vbscript guy... and so need some serious hand-holding here!

I have a third-party program that allows custom actions via vbscript. I have this set up to open a web page as a pop-up like so (Just the piece that isn't working- code is much longer):

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Do
crt.Sleep 100
Loop While objExplorer.Busy
szHTMLBody = _
"<font color='red'><b>Specify tech and truck:</b></font>" & _
"<hr>" & _
"<b><u>T</u>ech:</b>" & _
"<input type="text" name='tech' size='40' maxlength='512'>" & _
"<br>" & _
"<b><u>T</u>ruck:</b>" & _
"<input type=text name='truck' size='40' maxlength='512'>" & _
"<hr>" & _
"<button name='OK' AccessKey='O'><u>O</u>K</button>" & _
"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" & _
"<button name='Cancel' AccessKey='C'><u>C</u>ancel</button>"



objExplorer.ToolBar = 0
objExplorer.StatusBar = 0
objExplorer.Width = 200
objExplorer.Height = 500
objExplorer.Navigate "file://D:\test\Option.htm"
objExplorer.Document.Body.innerHTML = szHTMLBody
s = objExplorer.Document.Body.innerhtml
objExplorer.Visible = 1
objShell.AppActivate objExplorer 
intMessage = Msgbox(s,4096+4, "Schedule")
```

This works just fine if I run the code from an elevated command prompt, changing the innerHTML. If I launch this by way of the third party app it runs ok but will not change the inner HTML. I added the 's' variable to try and catch the current innerhtml and that msgbox displays blank when run from the app but shows the correct text when run from that elevated prompt.

MORE DETAILS:
The vbs file being called resides on a server with the 3rd party app. The app itself is run from a Remote Desktop Server. The html file exists on the Remote Desktop server - and I have tried moving it to the server with the vbs file with no change.

I also tried creating a "launcher" script to run this script using Shellexecute runas; if I enter the Admin user/password it works as expected. So I then found and added a script to the "launcher" script that showed the user that launched the program. This (at least in my head) verified this permission issue.

I have no idea where to even begin with this; ideally this will be "headless" so any user can click the button calling the vbs script and it will run, modifying the html accordingly before the user sees the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar popup, but I've used True and False for my objects instead of 1 and 0.

```
Function Main()
'Create blank Internet Explorer window
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Navigate "about:blank"

'Create list that will display specific details within the window
GrpType = Left(strPA, 5)
If GrpType <> "TTTT," And GrpType <> "3AYE," And InStr(GrpType, "NO,") = 0 Then
    New_Type = GrpType
    MyArray = Split(strPA, ",")
    GrpType = MyArray(1)
    n = 20
    
    objIE.document.body.innerHTML = "<title>TIN NOT FOUND</title><p class='msg'>TIN Not found: <span>" & _
    TIN & "</span></p><p class='not'>" & GrpType & _
    "</p><p class='ctrl'><input type='hidden' id='Submit' name='Submit' value='0'><input type='submit' value='OK' id='SubmitButton' onclick='document.all.Submit.value=1' autofocus></p>"
Else
    strPA = Replace(strPA, GrpType, "")
    MyArray = Split(strPA, ",")
End If
o = 1
z = 1

'This sets up the list data to resemble an Excel spreadsheet
If GrpType = "TTTT," Or GrpType = "3AYE," Or InStr(GrpType, "NO,") <> 0 Then
    For n = 0 To UBound(MyArray)
        If Disp_Type = "simple" Then
            If o = 6 And n <> UBound(MyArray) Then
               FormRow = MyArray(n) & "</td></tr><tr><td>" & ""
               o = 0
            ElseIf n = UBound(MyArray) Then
               FormRow = MyArray(n) & "</td></tr><table>"
            Else
               If o = 1 Then
                  FormRow = z & "</td><td>" & ""
                  z = z + 1
                  n = n - 1
               Else
                  FormRow = MyArray(n) & "</td><td>" & ""
               End If
            End If
        Else
            If o = 10 And n <> UBound(MyArray) Then
               FormRow = MyArray(n) & "</td></tr><tr><td>" & ""
               o = 0
            ElseIf n = UBound(MyArray) Then
               FormRow = MyArray(n) & "</td></tr><table>"
            Else
               If o = 1 Then
                  FormRow = z & "</td><td>" & ""
                  z = z + 1
                  n = n - 1
               Else
                  FormRow = MyArray(n) & "</td><td>" & ""
               End If
            End If
        End If
        o = o + 1
        List = List & FormRow
    Next
End If

'Set up the window metrics
objIE.Toolbar = False
objIE.StatusBar = False
objIE.Width = 1200
objIE.Height = 1800
objIE.Top = 50
objIE.Left = 50

'Set up the innerHTML code to display the list within the window
objIE.document.body.innerHTML = "<title>GROUP TYPE " & MyArray(2) & " FOUND</title><p class='msg'>Group Type " & MyArray(2) & " Returned for TIN: <span>" & _
            TIN & "</span></p><table border=0><tr><th>Seq#</th><th>Group Name</th><th>MPIN</th><th>Group Type</th><th>Group Start Date</th><th>Group Term Date</th></tr><tr><td>" & List & _
            "<p class='ctrl'><input type='hidden' id='Submit' name='Submit' value='0'><input type='submit' value='OK' id='SubmitButton' onclick='document.all.Submit.value=1' autofocus></p>"

'Allow the window to be viewed at this point
objIE.Visible = True

'Do this procedure until the user has clicked the OK/Submit button
Do Until FormExit = "GO"
     If objIE.document.all.Submit.Value = 1 Then
         objIE.Quit
         SetEverythingToNothing
         Exit Function
     End If
Loop

End Function
```

What you get is a popup like this:

[image]

This can be ran from pretty much any application. I do my debugging in Excel VBA, but I've used Macro Express Pro to run it as well as running it as a stand alone script.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
turns out after much head-banging that `AppActivate` and `Visible` were competing with one another somehow. Changing the order in the vb script has solved the problem.